# regular expression to match file path in perl

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl and i'm trying to extract the path of a file. Please help me with a suitable regular expression, this is my code:

```
$string = "D:/EZ-VPN/NKEMSL0-V02.txt------vpnclient server 156.37.253.97";
```

I want to extract `"D:/EZ-VPN/NKEMSL0-V02.txt"` and `"156.37.253.97"` and store it in 2 scalar variables. Please suggest a regular expression to extract these.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $string = "D:/EZ-VPN/NKEMSL0-V02.txt------vpnclient server 156.37.253.97"; 

$string =~ m/(.*?)--+.* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/;

print $1."\n";
print $2."\n";
```

This should work for you.

Perl gathers the results from the regex's brackes (so called capture groups) in the `$1, $2 ... $n` variables.

The filename is in `$1`, the IP adress is in `$2`.

Answer (score 2):

Using the string of 6 consecutive dashes to mark the end of the path:

```
my($path, $ipaddress) = ($string =~ m/(.*?)------.* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/);
```

Test script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "D:/EZ-VPN/NKEMSL0-V02.txt------vpnclient server 156.37.253.97"; 
my($path, $ipaddress) = ($string =~ m/(.*?)------.* (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/);
print "path = $path; IP = $ipaddress\n";
```

Output:

```
path = D:/EZ-VPN/NKEMSL0-V02.txt; IP = 156.37.253.97
```

Answer (score 2):

```
my ($x, $y) = split /------/, $string;
my ($z) = $y =~ /(\S+)\z/;
```